# Assembly loading happens twice

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-assembly, appdomain

I need to register some type(s) e.g MyHandler: IRequest in autofac. These types resides in an assembly 'A' that is not referenced so far and hence not loaded in appdomain. I tried to load assembly 'A' using Assembly.LoadFile(path), it gets loaded in app domain, but later this same dll is loaded in appdomain again by .net runtime and there are two instances of 'A' in app domain, which is a problem in my scenario.
using Autofac registration soure won't help either. I just want to know to prevent loading of 'A' by runtime, as I have already loaded it.

Comment: LoadFile() is wrong in 99.9% of all cases, use LoadFrom() instead.  You only ever use LoadFile() if you *want* to load an assembly more than once, that's very rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through **LoadFile** method you can load assemblies multiple times from different **PATHS**. Instead of LoadFile() try **LoadFrom()** or simply **Load()** the last  methods ensures that your assembly is loaded only once.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks. By the way where do they say in documentation that LoadFile will cause loading assemblies multiple time and the LoadFrom() and Load() won't.

Comment: in remarks section


_Remarks_


_Use the LoadFile method to load and examine assemblies that have the same identity, but are located in different paths. LoadFile does not load files into the load-from context, and does not resolve dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does. LoadFile is useful in this limited scenario because LoadFrom cannot be used to load assemblies that have the same identities but different paths; it will load only the first such assembly._